# How does a high pass filter and a low pass filter work for an amp?

Tags: amplifier, simulation, ltspice, low-pass, high-pass-filter

[image: Preamp circuit]

I'm researching how to incorporate treble and bass into an amp.

X1 is for bass, X2 is for treble and X3 is for volume.

Intuitively, for me, if a high pass filter only allows frequency above a certain threshold and the opposite for low pass filter, I can't see how these two could be added into the same circuit. The low frequency cannot pass through the high frequency threshold and vice versa.

I then fail to understand how they can then combine, i.e the frequency output of each resistor. Is this just superposition?

After playing around with values, the volume part of this circuit (X3) is also a mystery to me. If there is no resistance in X3, shouldn't this mean that the volume is max and therefore some voltage level above 0, but for this circuit it is 0.

Which raises another question, should volume be before the treble and bass settings or after?

This is a very simple circuit as far as I'm aware for treble and bass settings. I've seen many other claiming to be "simple",
https://www.eleccircuit.com/active-tone-controls-by-transistor/

But these are far beyond me.

If anyone could direct me to better circuits which doesn't have such a high difficulty rating I would appreciate that.

Comment: That circuit you have Drawn looks like it won’t work. What website did you find it on? If you guessed the circuit then I think you should take heed of the linked circuit and go study baxandall tone controls. Bass and treble control is not a beginners circuit until you understand RC high pass and RC low pass filters.

Comment: In case you'd like to read the paper that Andy is hinting towards, see this PDF of it: ["Negative Feedback
Tone Control," P. J. Baxandall, Wireless World, October 1952, pp 402-405](http://www.learnabout-electronics.org/Downloads/NegativeFeedbackTone.pdf). (The potentiometer used in the TREBLE adjustment in Figure 6 will be difficult to find, these days.)

Comment: Additional papers with more modern use of opamps can be found. ["Baxandall tone control revisited," M. V. Thomas, Wireless World, September 1974](http://www.keith-snook.info/wireless-world-magazine/Wireless-World-1974/Baxandall%20tone%20control%20revisited%20DCD.pdf) and ["Audio Tone Control using the TLC074 Operational Amplifier," SLOA042, Texas Instruments](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa042/sloa042.pdf). Of course, all these qualify for the "far beyond me" bin, I guess. Just as a note, when Baxandall published in 1952, he pretty much killed every other tone control idea in the market.